# Change a List variable through an Email

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I would like to add functionality to an email sent by sharepoint where an admin can simply click a link, or do something in the email sent to them, that will allow them to confirm the change in a list, without having to go to the actual webpage to do so.  Does sharepoint allow for this functionality, or must I edit the webpage itself?

Also, I am using Sharepoint-designer 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint allows you to send the link to the Item to the admin so that he can approve it right from clicking the link. You can do that with a workflow.

Example:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/use-an-approval-workflow-HA010154425.aspx

Comment: Does this work with Sharepoint 2013 as well?  I'm just making sure since I spent the last hour and a half reading up on "Collect Data from User" only to discover it isn't in 2013 :)

Comment: Yes it does, but the article is a bit old I guess, here's a better one to start with: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/all-about-approval-workflows-HA102771433.aspx